# How to check domain nameservers in PHP?

Tags: php, dns, lookup, nameservers

I need check what nameservers domain is using, but can't find correct solution in PHP.

I have tried `checkdnsrr();` and `dns_get_record();`, both of them do not show NS for some of domains that are working. `Whois` is also not a solution.

My purpose is to filter domains which have nameserver set and which haven't. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: `dns_get_record($host, DNS_NS);` is the only way. If there are nameserver entries missing in the return value of that function call the DNS server which the server PHP's running on it is talking to is most likely not up to date. That may be the case if you're in a company which has their own DNS servers which cache entries or do unregular updates.

Comment: You should provide sample domain for which `dns_get_record` doesn't work

Comment: dns_get_record('zinas.lv'); don't work for zinas.lv domain

Comment: If dns_get_record doesn't work for you, I'd suggest you to use a webservice like [link]http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/[/link]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should simple use `dns_get_record` function and optionally you can pass `DNS_NS` as second parameter.

For your domain `zinas.lv`  using

```
var_dump(dns_get_record('zinas.lv', DNS_NS));
```

I get:

> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["host"]=> string(8) "zinas.lv"
>   ["class"]=> string(2) "IN" ["ttl"]=> int(1655) ["type"]=> string(2)
>   "NS" ["target"]=> string(10) "ns1.dns.lv" } [1]=> array(5) {
>   ["host"]=> string(8) "zinas.lv" ["class"]=> string(2) "IN" ["ttl"]=>
>   int(1655) ["type"]=> string(2) "NS" ["target"]=> string(10)
>   "ns2.dns.lv" } }

So you can simply display those 2 dns using:

```
$dns = dns_get_record('zinas.lv', DNS_NS);

echo $dns[0]['target'].' '.$dns[1]['target'];
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for zinas.lv domain right now. And if it returns:

`array(0) {
}`

It means domain do not have nameservers set ?

Comment: @user3844395 Probably yes, but you should check it also using some other methods for example looking at `http://dnscheck.pingdom.com` and making sure there is no nameservers given. However as far as I know almost all domains (all even more) need to have set NS records  if they are active

Comment: there is about 150k domains, I can't manually check them all so i am looking automated solution. I hope it will work now. 

Also maybe there is a possibility to check domain NS records on public DNS ? For example `google 8.8.8.8` or `OpenDNS` ?

Comment: @user3844395 So simple first check the list and then manually check some of domains that have empty $dns. Probably some of your domains will be inactive so they'll return empty `$dns` array

Comment: @marcin-nobialek I just got few domains, that `$dns` responce is empty, but whois lookup show that there is an nameserver set. What does that mean ? Domain is quarantined, expiring or `dns_get_record` is failing?

Answer (score 6):

Use this function to get the nameserver's of any domain as an array:

```
function getDns($domain)
{
    $dns = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_NS);
    $nameservers = [];
    foreach ($dns as $current)
        $nameservers[] = $current['target'];
    return $nameservers;
}
```