# Using PHP to get nameservers?

Tags: php, dns

I'm trying to get the nameservers of multiple domains in PHP, but I keep getting this error for some domains:

```
PHP Warning:  dns_get_record(): A temporary server error occurred
```

For example, the domain `fightthesmears.com` gives that error, which is greatly slowing down the process.

That domain does have nameservers set:

```
Name Server: ns-78.awsdns-09.com
Name Server: ns-1526.awsdns-62.org
Name Server: ns-693.awsdns-22.net
Name Server: ns-1900.awsdns-45.co.uk
```

It looks like `dns_get_record` only works if a domain resolves.  If there are nameservers, but it doesn't resolve, it won't return the nameservers.

Is there a faster and more reliable way to get nameservers with PHP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check domain nameservers in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777551/how-to-check-domain-nameservers-in-php)

Comment: `dns_get_record()`  is notoriously unreliable. Does your environment allow shell commands? I've found this library to be a good wrapper for linux `dig`  https://github.com/hostinger/php-dig

Comment: @Haridarshan No, which answer did you think would have answered my question?

Comment: @TheGentleman Using dig also appears to fail.  I tried it with `fightthesmears.com` just now as well :/

Comment: That domain doesn't resolve on MX Toolbox either: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=dns%3afightthesmears.com&run=toolpage. Did you just configure the nameservers?

Comment: FYI: anything the WHOIS data shows you is _informational_ at best, and may not actually reflect reality. Your domain does not have its NS records configured correctly.

Comment: It's not my domain, it's just one of the random ones I run checking.  You can see it does work on https://intodns.com/fightthesmears.com

Comment: Then you should pick a test domain that's configured correctly, or explain why you need to test this broken one and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: @TheGentleman is there a way to specify for `dns_get_record` to pull the NS records from `a.gtld-servers.net` instead?  That's where IntoDNS is getting the data.

Comment: @ShadowAccount you can pass `DNS_NS` as second parameter to `dns_get_record` method to get NameServer records only

Comment: @Sammitch As I already explained, I'm running through a large amount of domains and trying to figure out why some are getting this error and trying to find a solution to it.

Comment: @Haridarshan I am doing that and it's the same issue :/

Comment: Well then none of PHP's built-in DNS functions will work for you. You're going to want to use something like @TheGentleman originally suggested that calls out to `dig` and can actually make the queries you want.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777551/how-to-check-domain-nameservers-in-php

Comment: @JCrook That's already been suggested.  Was there a specific answer there you're referring to?

Comment: I see ^ , no sorry just in general the comments and answers within that post seem more relatable to the issue here

Comment: Do not shell out to `dig` use a proper DNS library to do queries for `NS` record types. Depending on your needs you might need to reproduce the workings of an iterative nameserver and stop at the registry (parent) as child nameservers can be broken and not reply properly.  "trying to figure out why some are getting this error" You may need to understand how DNS delegation works, and the `NS` record types.

Comment: Right now `fightthesmears.com` is in a lame delegation case, see https://dnsviz.net/d/fightthesmears.com/YOS1HA/dnssec/ which is exactly the case I wrote about in parent commit: the nameservers given by registry are not themselves configured correctly. Any normal DNS resolver does the full iterative resolution, and hence goes up to the child, that replies "REFUSED" here. Depending on your use cases you may need to stop at registry (parent) or just consider the domain broken resolution-wise (which it certainly is).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek "use a proper DNS library" please share an example of such a library for PHP.

Comment: @Sammitch Any that does allow to do `NS` queries. Also, please see point 4. in second list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Or look at second parameter of `checkdnsrr`. But this is the minor part of the problem. See above the problem of lame delegation that would require far more than one call, hence a proper logic and design, depending on what needs to be achieved (which is not fully explained by poster); `dns_get_record` has `DNS_NS` as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks like dns_get_record only works if a domain resolves.

Depends on how you use the function (you are not really sharing any part of your code), and what you define as "resolves".

The specific domain you use as example is in a lame delegation state, as shown by https://dnsviz.net/d/fightthesmears.com/YOS1HA/dnssec/

Hence any single DNS call will iteratively resolve each node from root to children, that do reply "REFUSED" and hence the whole domain appears not resolving.

First, it you really need to query for nameservers, you have to properly use `DNS_NS` type in `dns_get_record`.  But this is not enough.

High level calls like that do the full resolution, so up to the child. In cases like the above, per design, it HAS TO reply that there is a DNS resolution error.

If you really need to get the nameservers (at the registry/parent side) no matter how badly broken the whole situation is, it means you have basically to redo yourself all iterations that a recursive nameserver is normally doing on your behalf, which means being able to send specific DNS packets to specific nameservers (which `dns_get_record` does not allow). Basically you start at root, and then you walk down the tree upon arriving at the child and you stop either there or backtrack one notch if you want to have the nameservers published by the registry in case they themselves do not reply properly.

It is basically what is called "finding zone cut". You can find such algorithm at RFC 7816 Appendix A for example.

I strongly suggest NOT TO attempt to do anything like that before having a solid grasp on how the DNS works, what zone cuts means, how `NS` records work, how a dot in a name is NOT necessarily a zone cut, what safeguards you need to employ such as timeouts, retries (UDP vs TCP), converging towards faster nameserver, and so on.

You are not sharing a lot about your constraints, setup of goal, so difficult to advise you in most suited solutions, hopefully the above gives you hints.

For example, you could have shortcuts, if you said "all my domains are .com and .net", then for example it could be good enough for you to just always query directly Verisign (the registry of these two TLDs) authoritative nameservers to find the delegations.

Absolutely DO NOT shell out to run commands like `dig`, it is a bad idea on all fronts:

- maintenance/deployment wise, you are now bound on having `dig` installed on the system you want your software running, which is an assumption that may not be true and not under your control in any way,
- performance wise, you will suffer a big hit (especially if not careful as it can often be seen with a fork from PHP to the shell and then from the shell to `dig`; each fork can be costly)
- security wise, you will be open to a whole bunch of problems around quoting, escaping, parameters expansion, etc. basically all kinds of XRF type attacks,
- programming wise, it makes no sense to shell out to run `dig` (which sends DNS queries), as any relevant programming language as a least one DNS library able to send DNS packets (because at the base there is nothing exceptional or to compare not at all more complicated than TLS let us say: DNS uses binary packets over port 53 in TCP and UDP sockets, so it is just a matter of parsing and building them, not rocket science for the core protocol part); and of course `dig` was made for human consumption, so it is absolutely not wise to try parsing its output in any way (and any library doing that should be avoided because it is guaranteed to break one day when upgrading `dig`, is guaranteed to break in non funny and indescriptive ways at any time for various `dig` edge cases - think IDN handling for example that changes between `dig` versions - and is basically avoiding to write some "simple" binary encoded/decoder for the DNS protocol as it should be done and relying on a false assumption that parsing a human tailored output - which is what `dig` gives - with regular expressions is the solution to everything).

Another separate point as you quote a whois output, two points in fact:

- in theory, whois and DNS are separate; you should see the same data in both (regarding nameservers), but it may not be guaranteed; so in theory it is better to grab nameservers data out of the DNS... but in some cases whois can be a good enough workaround, if you consider it is heavily rate limited by registry, and the format varies a lot (you are not telling which TLDs you are focusing on), which brings us to the second point:
- for anything like that, use RDAP, not whois; it is its philosophical successor; it gives the same data (and more) with a big benefit: the answer is structured, as it is JSON contrary to whois which uses free form text.

Also on another separate note:

> I'm trying to get the nameservers of multiple domains in PHP [..] which is greatly slowing down the process.

You do not share details of your setup, but in case like that, parallelism is the obvious first step to increase performances. Each DNS query per domain is (mostly) unrelated to other domains, so you can fire them at the same time, in batch of 10, 100 or more, depending on your setup. You need of course the appropriate design and support functions, that is "an asynchronous DNS library", that is able to fire multiple DNS query and call back your own code in a way once results are coming. That way you can scale and no domain broken/long resolution should block the whole process.

Comment: I selected this answer since you did such a great job explaining the problem.  I ended up `Net_DNS2` and set it to query `a.gtld-servers.net` for all `.com` and `.net` domains.  I'm continuing to use `dns_get_record` for the others.  But that's okay because querying `a.gtld-servers.net` is so much faster and around 70% of my list is `.com` domains.